# skipping slow query log

Tags: mysql

If I save a statement in a text file and call it at command prompt like this...

mysql -uroot -pPassWord DB_Name < somefile.txt

The statements taking a long time do not appear in the slow query log even though all the statements do appear in the general and binary logs. Is it a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it a bug *where*?

For all I know, the slow query log could be disabled, or your long-running statements could run in less time, than `@@long_query_time` or examine less, than `@@min_examined_row_limit` rows.

EDIT:
Well, here is your answer then. Actually, I was never aware of the fact, that it's possible to log *statements* such as `alter table` to the slow query log. It appears, however, that it can be done.
Reference: [log-slow-admin-statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-slow-admin-statements).

Comment: I have checked all the 4 points mentioned by you... a) slow query log is enabled b) statement is taking more than 5 minutes c) long_query_time is 2 seconds d) It is an alter statement